# Chart column grid between

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.
Now I have a column chart like this.

[image]

But I need the grid to be aside to the column like this.

[image]

How can I do it?

---

My data are from DataGridView, so my code was look like this.

```
var ser = chart1.Series.Add("ana");
ser.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
ser.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

//X value is string
ser.XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;

//Y value is int
ser.YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;

chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

And the data in DataGridView is simple.

```
-------------
|Month|Sales|
-------------
| Jan | 17  |
-------------
| Feb | 28  |
-------------
| Mar | 19  |
-------------
```

Comment: Put some effort, if face any problems then post here.

Comment: You should show us how you add the `DataPoints`! What are their `X-Values` and `X-ValueType` ?

Answer (score 2):

`GridLines` go with `DataPoints` and `Labels` go with `GridLines`, but..

You can set the `Interval` and the `Minimum` for the `X-Axis` to tweak them apart :

[image]

but there are a few extras to watch out for..

```
// get a reference
ChartArea chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

// don't start at 0
chartArea1.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = false;

// pick your interval
double interval = 1D;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = interval;

// set minimum at the middle
chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = interval / 2d;

// pick a column width (optional)
chart1.Series[0].SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "30");

// we want the labels to sit with the points, not the grid lines..
// so we add custom labels for each point ranging between the grid lines..
for (int i = 0; i <  chart1.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
{
    DataPoint dp = chart1.Series[0].Points[i];
    chartArea1.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add( (0.5d + i) * interval, 
                                       (1.5d + i) * interval, dp.XValue.ToString());
}
```

**Update:**

As your updated question shows, you are using data-binding with strings as **X-Values**. This is very convenient, but goes against the core nature of the Chart control. All its xalues, be it `X-Value` or any of the `Y-Values` are internally stored as doubles.

Random **strings don't convert to double** and while you can conveniently add `DataPoints` with strings as `X-Values`, all sorts of ugly issues come up as a consequence.

First have a look at the `X-Values` themselves: As I said they are double; when you check their values you will see they all are 0. And where are the string values? They are placed in the labels.

One problem often found it that you now can't access the `X-Values` with [value expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx).

Another problem is that we now can't give a **range** of `x-Values` for custom labels.

Solution:  If we need custom labels, we must change the data!

Data binding is fine, just make sure to add a numeric column to you datasource containing a month number and set it as the `XValueMember` of the series!

You can make that column it invisible in your `DataGridView`.

Finally you will want to create the custom labels, pretty much as before; just change their content to pull from the string column containing the month names.

Here is what it looks like here:

[image]

Comment: My bad. I updated my question with more detail. I'm using data from dataGridView and the interval trick seems not working.

Comment: I see. You do not have __real__ X-Values then at the moment. The Strings you are using are only used for the axis labels; if you look at the X-Values of the created DataPoints you will see that __they all are 0__ and therefore the trick will not work. I'll update the answer tomorrow..

Comment: Thanks. I know there's workaround by adding those data manually with AddPoint and CustomLabels.Add, but I'm looking for the better way to do this (if there is).

Comment: I have updated my answer; the main point is: If you use string as (pseudo) x-values, you will not be able to use all features of the chart control.