# Top X-axis label not showing Windows Form chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am trying to draw a chart for an application I am developing for Windows Form. I am using the Chart Control, and customizing it programmatically.

I have learned a lot so far, since it is a .NET control and therefore there is plenty of documentation over the Internet on this issue.

However, something is putting me out since yesterday: I've enabled the two secondary labels for my 2D line chart (AxisX2 and AxisY2). The problem is that the label for these axes only show up for the second one (AxisY2), altough they are created and configured exactly the same way.

I've got a screenshot of my application so that you can see what I am talking about:

[image: WinChart without top-label]

The code for the creation of these two secondary axes is given bellow:

```
        var xAxisTop = new Axis
        {
            Minimum = 0,
            Maximum = 100,
            Interval = 5.0,
            LabelStyle = new LabelStyle { ForeColor = Color.Black, Enabled = true, Font = new Font("Verdana", 18.0f) },
            Title = "Pos (%)",
            LineWidth = 2,
            MajorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.DimGray },
            MinorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.DimGray },
            IsMarksNextToAxis = true,
            Enabled = AxisEnabled.True
        };
        chartArea1.AxisX2 = xAxisTop;

        var yAxisTop = new Axis
        {
            Minimum = 0,
            Maximum = 100,
            Interval = 5.0,
            LabelStyle = new LabelStyle { ForeColor = Color.Black, Enabled = true, Font = new Font("Verdana", 18.0f) },
            Title = "Load (%)",
            LineWidth = 2,
            MajorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.DimGray },
            MinorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.DimGray },
            IsMarksNextToAxis = true,
            Enabled = AxisEnabled.True
        };
        chartArea1.AxisY2 = yAxisTop;
```

I literally have no idea what is going one. Can someone help me?

Comment: No, but I haven't done it for the Y secondary axis either, and it worked for it.

Comment: I don't get your point. I enabled the AxisY2 and it showed up on the chart area. I did the same for the AxisX2 and only the labled are missing. I checked the XAxisType and YAxisType for my series and both are set to Primary.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the code for adding the `DataPoints` but my crystal ball says: Most likely your `Axes` both are perfectly ok and your problem stems from your `X-Values`.

Your `Y-Values` are, as usual, numeric but if your `X-Values` are not, **they still will seem to be OK but they are not!**: The `Labels` do show just fine as they are created from the strings you feed in, but the `X-Values` actually are all `0`s. Check it in the debugger!!

This is a **common mistake** and **it only shows** when you are trying to actually **use** those `X-Values`, for example by using a numeric formatting string or do a calculation or, as you are doing, try to use them implictly, by setting a `Minimum` and `Maximum` for your secondary `X-Axis`.

As all values are `0` there is no room between `Minimum` and `Maximum` at all and nothing is showing..

Check on the code that adds the `DataPoints` and make sure it adds numbers, not strings for the X-Values as well!

See [here for a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424551/c-sharp-windows-form-chart-column-grid-between/32426280?s=2|1.1231#32426280) and its discussion and solution! Scroll to the Update! (( SO still doesn't allow anchors in posts :-( ))

**Update:** I just found **one more reason** why the labels on a **secondary** axis don't show: They only show if you **also** show the labels on the **primary** axis. If you don't want that you must **not disable** them! Instead you can set their `LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Transparent` !

Obviously this is not your case, as the primary axis does show its labels.